# Unmanned Drone vs Conventional Manned Fighter in Combat: How realistic?

Tags: unmanned-aerial-vehicle, dogfighting

How far are we / Is it even viable to think of a scenario where a drone gets employed to counter a conventional manned fighter?

I can see several benefits:

- Free of the G-restrictions of a human the drone is free to undergo far more severe manouveres
- Cheaper testing costs since a drone crash isn't as expensive / as unpalatable as the death of a test pilot
- More risk appetite during actual combat since a human life is not at stake
- The removal of the cockpit and life support / protective systems (e.g. No O2 tanks / No pressurization / No ejector seats) leading to a weight reduction, performance improvement and design flexibility. Perhaps allowing greater munitions loads etc.
- The possibility of undertaking some version of suicidal yet mutually destructive manouveres that are out of question in conventional dogfights.

On the other hand, several limitations I can think of:

- Poorer field of vision & situational awareness of a remote drone operator operating via cameras and sensors
- The lag between control and reaction inherent to today's drone remote operator systems. Though how much of this could be improved via better technology is a crucial question. The current generation seems to use Ku band satellite signals. Could some form of ground network (but beyond enemy reach) provide more responsive controls? How close have we approached the fundamental physics latency limits even with existing satellite transmission technology.

<strike>As a totally different alternative, is the possibility of an unmanned, autonomous drone realistic? How far are we on the AI / sensors side where a autonomous decision engine can realistically be a good match for a human adversary in a dogfight. The autonomous option would make the control lag issue redundant.</strike>  (Redacted to focus the question on manned drones)

Comment: As this stands it seems way too broad and might venture into opinion. Maybe this could be separated into two questions of "advantages/disadvantages of UCAV vs. manned fighter" and "what technology is available/needed for a totally autonomous UCAV fighter?"

Comment: A small aircraft that flies autonomously with assistance from a remote source, has no pilot and no need for a cockpit or life support systems, can maneuver rapidly in response to the enemy aircraft, can make maneuvers pilots are not capable of, has no need of self-preservation and will do whatever is necessary to destroy the enemy? We already have something similar, it's called a radar-guided missile

Comment: **1.** G-limits dictated by airframe & payloads, not the human. Eg, F/A-18E/F & F-35C are limited to 7.5 g's; F-16 is limited to ~5-7 g's with drop tanks.

**2.** Life support is a small fraction of total a/c weight

**3.** A survivable & *effective* a/c (manned or no) will still cost a lot. In many ways, 5th gen a/c are already flown by [albeit narrow] AI.

**4.** Testing a complex, modern 5th gen a/c is time-taking. Replacing a well-tested meat brain with an e-brain will add more testing, not less.

**5.** NATO doctrine is domination, not attrition. Kamikaze-like is unlikely.

Comment: Also, maneuverability is both a) very expensive (eg, stronger+heavier airframe, larger wings, a second engine or more powerful engine(s), and/or thrust vectoring) and b) losing relevance in modern air to air combat, so 6th gen fighters could very well be _less_ maneuverable than 5th gen ones.

Comment: One advantage of an autonomous UCAV over a manned fighter is that it can be made a lot smaller, and therefore less easily detected. This factor alone would probably prove decisive in some situations, particularly at low level, where in the future UCAVs may well be engaged in missions against ground targets, and where the manned fighter's radar and other sensors are least effective due to ground clutter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We're nowhere near good enough with our AI for a computer simulant to best a human pilot in a dogfight unless the odds are further stacked against the human (computer flies a superior aircraft, computer has enhanced knowledge of "reality", computer has advantage in numbers, computer ignores physical limitations of plane or pilot without consequence). Most computer pilot AIs in combat sims are some combination of the very simplistic "locate your opponent, put your lift vector on him and pull up hard" and the more complex "human is doing this, so the best counter-move is this". There's also no small amount of "I am a game, the purpose of my existence is to be enjoyable for the human, so while I must present a challenge, I must not require my human to attend a year of combat flight school before he stands a chance".

These are the basics of ACM taught to every fighter pilot, however these strategies will get you shot down against a competent human pilot every time, for two reasons:

- "Line up and pull up" tends to settle you into a horizontal "one-circle" turning fight to conserve energy. In that fight, the first pilot to realize it's happening and pull vertical can tighten the turning radius by trading speed for altitude, getting inside and cutting across his opponent's turning circle for a good if somewhat high-offset firing chance. If the opponent sticks with "line up and pull up" he will do just the opposite, trading altitude for speed, increasing his turning radius and putting his tailpipe in front of his opponent's nose.
- Moves and countermoves in air combat are a fluid dance that computers are plain bad at. Computers can beat humans in chess because the number of valid moves is fairly low, so the computer can calculate the most advantageous chain of several dozen moves quickly. However, computers are relatively bad at Go, because both the total game tree complexity and the available moves on each player-turn are massive.

  Air combat is similar; while there are a few basic strategies, there are infinite possibilities, and because air combat, though "turn-based", involves a different kind of "turn" from those in chess or Go, the computer doesn't get to sit there and think about its move for several seconds; it has to make the best move it can think of in a fraction of a second or else the human will get to make several "moves" before the computer reacts to the first one, and the way computers think, making it decide quickly usually boils down either to simplifying the decision-making or deciding in a random way.
- Prioritization is still an area where computer AI is weak. Against one opponent, where your objective is to shoot that opponent down, a computer could do quite well. Facing the primary mission objective of completing a bombing run, with potentially hundreds of aircraft in the sky and thousands of military (and civilian) ground vehicles and people in a combat theater, making the decision of what object deserves your primary attention any given second is something even human pilots don't always do well. Most AIs in combat sims are fairly scripted; either the purpose of an enemy's existence is to shoot down the player, or it focuses on its mission until it cannot ignore the player. Real combat is somewhere in between, especially when your mission is something like CAS or BARCAP where your job isn't one fixed point on the ground or one plane in the air.

Now, computers have some advantages that are considered "cheating" in combat sims but would apply to an unmanned fighter against a manned one. First is the ability to sustain maneuvers in excess of a human's G-limit. As long as the airframe can handle it, the computer can pull 12g turns, or -12g, whatever. Second is that the weight of a human, plus the "man-machine interface" of the cockpit systems, is greater than the mass of a computer directly connected to the instrumentation. The computer is also much faster at working with the aircraft's systems than a human could ever be, so a computer pilot, within a couple seconds of seeing a "blip" on the radar, could have the target locked up, while a human, given the same blip at the same time, would still be slewing tracking gates in the B-scope.

A third big advantage is 720* visibility. Humans have about a 170* "cone" of visual response, and a fairly poor 5-10* window of actual focus and acuity. With an unmanned craft, we can install cameras covering virtually 360* around the aircraft in the horizontal and vertical, and have the computer monitor and track objects within the full field of vision, as well as in IR or other non-visible light spectrums, much more efficiently than a human could do the same with the same camera systems.

Therefore, the first fully unmanned combat aircraft is very unlikely to look or work like a manned one, because its designers will have done things that would be bad decisions in a manned craft, but will give the computer a maneuverability, speed or visibility advantage that could compensate for more simplistic decision-making of the AI.

Comment: The first advantage is numbers. Being able to put more weapon platforms in the air (and keep them almost indefinitely) is key to winning the attrition game (cue Lanchester's square law).

Comment: Excellent answer. Any comments about a remotely human controlled drone? It seems to have a hybrid of the features you discussed. i.e. A human can overcome AI limitations while still getting the advantage of high G manouveres & weight reduction. Multiple human controllers dealing with weapons / flight or different sectors might also alleviate the cone of vision restrictions. OTOH, you lose out on the fast response time of a true unmanned drone.

Comment: Ah, didn't notice that I got put on hold. Too bad. I was hoping to hear your insights about remotely manned drones.

Comment: Anyone who believes that a computer can't fly an aircraft in combat has probably never played Microsoft Combat Flight Simulator or one of the more recent air to air combat PC games. As a general principle, if a computer can manoeuver an aircraft realistically in virtual space, it can also do it in reality. In fact, computer systems should be able able to control and co-ordinate UCAVs in combat in ways that human pilots would find impossible.

Comment: @JSouthworth MFS and other flight simulators cheat because they totally control the environment. They know in absolute terms where every point of interest is. They can not only predict the wind 500 yards in front of the aircraft, the computer can ignore it if you aren't paying close attention to simulated control inputs. Similarly, planes you aren't looking at closely enough to tell they're simulated will stop pitching and banking through the virtual space and just point and move.

Comment: Saying AI can pilot drones with ease because they've been doing it in MFS for decades is like saying designing fully articulated walking robots should have been trivial because Quake was out 30 years ago. If you actually believe that, you have no clue.

Comment: KeithS, you have a point, in combat simulators the same computer controls the environment as controls the opposing aircraft, but that's a minor issue and one which you could in principle easily solve by using two independent computers, one to control the environment and one for the enemy aircraft.

Comment: Nobody would claim that Microsoft Combat Flight Simulator 98 is totally realistic, fighter aircraft in World War Two didn't have radar gunsights for one thing but the realism of the manoeuvering and tactics is good, fly the Mark 1 Spitfire against a formation of Me110s, attacking from the rear and you'll be impressed by the tactics they use to get on your tail. I wouldn't rate a manned fighter's chances against a bunch of UCAVs at low level.